# How to clean up boot menu of Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

I have dual boot set up with Windows 10 and Linux. The UEFI boot menu works fine and shows the insalled OSs. However, wenn I select "Windows Boot Manager", instead of booting up Windows, I get to choose between two different Windows installations.

Only one of them works.

Also, I know the origin of the broken one: I overwrote Windows once on one hard drive and put a fresh install on a new hard drive.

How can I delete the entry in the Windows Boot Manager for the broken (non-existent) Windows installation?

Comment: ***Be very careful.***  Learn about the [windows BCD](https://www.cio.com/article/3197847/working-with-bcd-in-windows-10.html).  Use a tool called `bcdedit` [that comes with windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc721886(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to edit the entries.  I say again, be ***very*** careful.  BCD replaced Boot.ini years ago and has changed very little so don't worry if you see references to Vista or 7 in the docs.  Start by running `bcdedit /enum` and look at the entries.  You will probably see your problem.

Comment: Also.. if you want to be super sure you don't hose your boot loader and lower your risk, instead of trying to *remove* the entry, make the one you want to keep the default and add a long timeout to automatically boot into it.  Then shorten the timeout and ignore the extra entry.. or delete it at that point as you will know that you have the correct one.

Comment: I turned your comments into an answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Run a terminal as administrator, e.g. by hitting <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, typing `cmd` and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Run `bcdedit /enum`
3. Try to identify the offending boot entry and copy its ID
4. In case you are in a PowerShell, type `cmd` now to open a regular shell, as the next command doesn't work in PowerShell
5. Run `bcdedit /delete <id> /f` where `<id>` is something like `{asdf-01234-...}`

Comment: Such a smart answer.. I think I will upvote ;).  BTW, `Open PowerShell` should be Open a console or terminal.  Powershell has nothing to do with this.